# VBA type mismatch when value is calculated by a formula in the cell

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("F2:F220")
 
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

If Range("G2:G220").Value < 0 Then
    MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

End If 
End If
End Sub
```

There's a formula in column G that calculates the value from numbers in column F. I wanted a popup when a result in G has a negative value. The type mismatch is on the line `If Range("G2:G220") ...` The column is formatted as Number, but it shows as Variant/Variant. I assume this is because the cell contents are actually a formula?

Is there a way round this without introducing 'helper' columns?

This is only my second bit of VBA so I'm happy to hear if you spot any other errors!

Comment: `Range("G2:G220").Value` is a 2D `Variant` array holding 218 values: you can't compare an array with `< 0` like that, you need to either use `COUNTIF` to count the number of negative values in that range, or iterate the cells and verify them one by one - i.e. the problem is the number of cells involved, not their content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Restrict the Number of Results

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const KeyAddress As String = "F2:F220"
    Const CheckColumn As Variant = "G" ' e.g. "A" or 1
    Const MaxResults As Long = 1
    
    ' Define 'KeyCells'.
    Dim KeyCells As Range: Set KeyCells = Range(KeyAddress)
    ' Define the range of cells that have changed and are part of 'KeyCells'.
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, KeyCells)
    ' Check if there are any cells that have changed and are part of 'KeyCells'.
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ' Check if there is more than 'MaxResults' cells that have changed and
    ' are part of 'KeyCells'.
    If rng.Cells.Count > MaxResults Then GoSub checkMoreCells
    
    ' Calculate the offset between 'Key' and 'Check' columns.
    Dim ColOff As Long: ColOff = Columns(CheckColumn).Column - KeyCells.Column
    
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        ' Check if the value in 'Check' column is negative.
        If cel.Offset(, ColOff).Value < 0 Then
            MsgBox "Cell '" & cel.Address(False, False) & "' has changed " _
                 & "to '" & cel.Value & "'."
        End If
    Next cel

    Exit Sub

checkMoreCells:
    Dim msg As Variant
    msg = MsgBox("There could be '" & rng.Cells.Count & "' results. " _
               & "Are you sure you want to continue?", _
               vbYesNo + vbCritical, _
               "More Than One Cell")
    If msg = vbYes Then Return
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Range("F2:F220"), Target) 'Target is already a Range...
    'any changed cells in F2:F220 ? 
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        'loop over the changed cell(s)
        For Each c in rng.Cells
            'check value in ColG...   
            If c.Offset(0, 1).Value < 0 Then
                MsgBox "Cell " & c.Address & " has changed."
            End If
        Next c 
    End If

End Sub
```

Edit: I realize it's not exactly clear whether you want to know if there's *any* negative numbers in Col G, or if you want to track row-by-row.  This code does the latter.

Comment: Thank you, but I got the mismatch error again. @VBasic2008 provided a perfect solution below.

Comment: Had a typo (fixed)  Glad you got a solution